# Ambiguous formula for hypercomplex multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I have been reading on *Cayley-Dickson construction* lately.
I was very surprised to find three distinct versions of the multiplication definition, please inspect the following links:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction
  $(a,b)(c,d) = (ac-d^\ast b, da+bc^\ast)$
- https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cayley-Dickson+construction
  $(a,b)(c,d) = (ac-db^\ast, a^\ast d+cb)$
- [http://www.zipcon.net/~swhite/docs/math/quaternions/Cayley-Dickson.html](http://www.zipcon.net/%7Eswhite/docs/math/quaternions/Cayley-Dickson.html)
  $(a,b)(c,d) = (ac-bd^\ast, bc^\ast+da)$

Which one of these is the 'standard' definition? Why are they even providing the distinct ones?

Comment: One of them notes *There is more than one way to arrange the conjugates so that everything will work out, and the choice is arbitrary, but will later affect the terminology about “handedness”.* It's possible there is a typo somewhere, I didn't slog through it. But it is also very likely that there isn't really a universally accepted version, that people use one of a small set of variations that they like. Don't spend too much time worrying about which one is right as long as you have one that is correct and works for you.

Comment: Also, I think if you actually transcribed the three definitions from the links, you'd have a good chance of someone helping you slog through the details to see if anything is wrong. Forcing people to parse through three entire webpages for variants on a single definition is not going to go as smoothly.  They might not even figure out which formula you were looking at.

Comment: Thanks, I have included the formulas.
How is it possible that multiple formulas are allowed? Commutativity is lost in higher algebras thus all these versions might lead to different results.

Comment: For example, in $\mathbb R^2$, you can define complex multiplication to be either $(ac-bd, ad+bc)$ or $(ac-bd, -ad-bc)$.  The second copy just uses the copy of $\mathbb C$ which is the image of the conjugation map.  Representations aren't always unique.

Comment: Changing the representation does not necessarily change the thing being defined.